# How to count total number of table rows from ajax response? How to create search field for that table?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, datatables

I am getting table data from ajax response like this :

```
function fetch_data(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "menu_table.php",
    method: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
      $('#menu_table_data').html(data);
    }
  });
}

fetch_data();
```

Table:

```
<table id="menu_table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="centerText" data-field="item_id">ID</th>
      <th class="centerText" data-field="name">Name</th>
      <th class="centerText" data-field="price">Price</th>
      <th class="centerText" data-field="type">Type</th>
      <th class="centerText" data-field="image">Image</th>
      <th class="centerText" data-field="description">Description</th>
      <th class="centerText" data-field="cooking">Instructions</th>
      <th class="centerText" data-field="ingredients">Ingredients</th>
      <th class="centerText" data-field="warnings">Warnings</th>
      <th class="centerText" data-field="Storage">Storage</th>
      <th class="centerText" data-field="Size">Size</th>
      <th class="centerText" data-field="edit">Edit</th>
      <th class="centerText" data-field="delete">Delete</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody style="text-align:center;" id="menu_table_data"></tbody>
</table>
```

1. How do I count total number of rows from ajax response?
2. How can I create a search field to search from this table?

**menu_table.php:**

```
while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($search))
{
$output .= '<tr><td>'.$data['id'].'</td>
            <td><div class="text_area">'.$data['name'].'</div></td>
            <td>'.$data['price'].'</td>
            <td>'.$data['type'].'</td>
            <td><div id="div_image">
            <img src="uploaded_images/'.$data['image'].'" class="thumbnail" height="100" width="80" /></div></td>
            <td><div class="text_area">'.$data['description'].'</div></td>
            <td><div class="text_area">'.$data['cooking_instructions'].'<div></td>
            <td><div class="text_area">'.$data['ingredients'].'</div></td>
            <td><div class="text_area">'.$data['allergen_warnings'].'</div></td>
            <td>'.$data['storage_instructions'].'</td>
            <td>'.$data['case_size'].'</td>   <td><a class="btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-edit" role="button" onclick="EditModal(`'.$data['id'].'`,`'.$data['name'].'`,`'.$data['price'].'`,`'.$data['description'].'`,`'.$data['type'].'`,`'.$data['cooking_instructions'].'`,`'.$data['ingredients'].'`,`'.$data['allergen_warnings'].'`,`'.$data['storage_instructions'].'`,`'.$data['case_size'].'`,`'."uploaded_images/".$data['image'].'`)"></a></td>   <td><a class="btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove" role="button" onclick="DeleteModal('.$data['id'].')"></a></td><tr>';}
```

Comment: What does the response look like?

Comment: I am getting data from database by ajax and I am showing it in table. Everything is working fine. I dont know how to count total tr from response of ajax.

Comment: Response is table data that is inserted inside table by `$('#menu_table_data').html(data);`

Comment: Why don't you create json response that holds table html and total number of rows

Comment: you should use these libraries `jquery.dataTables.css` and `jquery.dataTables.js`.. these libraries provide auto search and total rows

Comment: The table i am using also contains search field but its not working on data that i get from ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the response to the request is the plain HTML in your second code example, you can put it in a jQuery selector, then `find()` the `tr` elements in it, like this:

```
function fetch_data(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "menu_table.php",
    method: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
      var rowCount = $('#menu_table_data').html(data).find('tr').length;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Then that's how many `tr` is in the response. Without you showing us what the HTML it's going to be hard to help you

Comment: I have inserted the response

Comment: That appears to be an image. We need to see the HTML

Comment: @Shaifu - You seem to have only 1 row(`<tr>`) in your output.

Comment: Thanks @Rory McCrossan

Answer (score 3):

Just use the Selector.length to get row count. and even you don't need to initialize a variable if u directly call the `$('#menu_table_data > tr').length` and that's it. 
EDITED

```
$('#menu_table_data tr').length;
```

**EDIT**

```
 $output .= '<tr><td>'.$data['id'].'</td>
        <td><div class="text_area">'.$data['name'].'</div></td>
        <td>'.$data['price'].'</td>
        <td>'.$data['type'].'</td>
        <td><div id="div_image">
        <img src="uploaded_images/'.$data['image'].'" class="thumbnail" height="100" width="80" /></div></td>
        <td><div class="text_area">'.$data['description'].'</div></td>
        <td><div class="text_area">'.$data['cooking_instructions'].'<div></td>
        <td><div class="text_area">'.$data['ingredients'].'</div></td>
        <td><div class="text_area">'.$data['allergen_warnings'].'</div></td>
        <td>'.$data['storage_instructions'].'</td>
        <td>'.$data['case_size'].'</td>   <td><a class="btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-edit" role="button" onclick="EditModal(`'.$data['id'].'`,`'.$data['name'].'`,`'.$data['price'].'`,`'.$data['description'].'`,`'.$data['type'].'`,`'.$data['cooking_instructions'].'`,`'.$data['ingredients'].'`,`'.$data['allergen_warnings'].'`,`'.$data['storage_instructions'].'`,`'.$data['case_size'].'`,`'."uploaded_images/".$data['image'].'`)"></a></td>   <td><a class="btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove" role="button" onclick="DeleteModal('.$data['id'].')"></a></td></tr>';
```

use this..

Comment: just close the tr tag it is not closed..check and correct it. and then try getting the row count.

Comment: EDIT in my answer.

Comment: Now i can count correct rows but by method mentioned by @Rory McCrossan

Answer (score 1):

**How do I count total number of rows from ajax response?**

You could use the JQuery `.length` function **after** successfully loading the `tbody` contents.

```
function fetch_data(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "menu_table.php",
    method: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
      $('#menu_table_data').html(data);
      var no_of_rows = $('#menu_table_data').find('tr').length;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Still no luck. Showing only 1 record.

Comment: Ofcourse it does, your `output` seems to have only 1 row. (only 1 `<tr>`) in your output.

Answer (score 1):

after you change html

```
$("#menu_table_data tr")
```

will give you all table rows

to create a search field

```
var searchKey = "some given key in some form";
$("#menu_table_data tr").each(function(item){
 if(item.text().indexOf(searchKey)>=0){
     item.addClass("hideResult");
 }else{
     item.removeClass("hideResult");
 }
});
```

and you can hide negative results

```
.hideResult{
    display: none;
}
```

also you can filter data without append it at the begining. $ function takes aprameters other than selectors too.

for example

```
var somehtml = '<div>some text</div>';

$(somehtml).text() //this will gives you 'some text'
```

Comment: Thank you sir, I'll give this a try.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna search only on page you can use that :

```
$.extend($.expr[":"], {
        "containsIN": function(elem, i, match, array) {
            return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || "").toLowerCase().indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
        }
    });
```

you can use that html onKeyUp:

```
function searchOnKeyUp(input,selector){
        $(selector).each(function(){ $(this).hide(); })
        $(selector + ':containsIN('+input.value+')').show();
    }
```

And for other question I can say that I think you can use like that:

```
$('#menu_table_data').children('tr').length;
```

Comment: `$('#menu_table_data').children('tr').length;` not giving correct records. I'll try your search method as well.